# Trouble installing python3-rosdep. (python3-docutils is missing or obsolete?)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have the following problem installing python3-rosdep via apt:

When I try to run

```
sudo apt install -y python3-rosdep
```

I get the following response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-rosdep : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rosdistro but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rospkg but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python3-rosdep-modules (>= 0.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So what I did then, is I tried to install python3-catkin-pkg myself by running:

```
sudo apt install -y python3-catkin-pkg
```

With the following response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-catkin-pkg : Depends: python3-docutils but it is not installable
                          Depends: python3-pyparsing but it is not installable
                          Depends: python3-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.23) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So naturally I tried to install python3-docutils:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-docutils
```

Which yielded a response that confused me a lot:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-docutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-docutils' has no installation candidate
```

Python3-docutils has no installation candidate??
I am very confused by this.

I am running Ubuntu focal 20.04.3

Help is greatly appreciated, Thanks a lot in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386959/trouble-installing-python3-rosdep.-(python3-docutils-is-missing-or-obsolete?)/) by [schmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/74713/schmi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-21**:
You may want to try using `aptitude` to see whether it can provide some more insight into why installation is impossible.

These kinds of things are difficult to diagnose as it's very difficult to reliably reproduce them (it depends on the state of your local configuration, apt database + apt sources and their state).

**Comment by [schmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/74713/schmi/) on 2021-09-21**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for your comment. I have gotten the following response from aptitude:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-catkin-pkg{ab} python3-catkin-pkg-modules{ab} python3-rosdep python3-rosdep-modules{a} python3-rosdistro{a} python3-rosdistro-modules{a} python3-rospkg{a} python3-rospkg-modules{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 165 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,077 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-catkin-pkg-modules : Depends: python3-docutils which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

                              Depends: python3-pyparsing which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized that his has nothing really to do with ros.
I will close this issue.

(My solution was reinstalling the complete os, I had tried everything)

---

Originally posted by [schmi](https://answers.ros.org/users/74713/schmi/) with karma: 16 on 2021-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0